# My message got duplicated when reloading the page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my PHP and MySQL code. I was creating a private messaging system but unfortunately, each time I reload the page, the last message sent is duplicated in the database and then displayed twice, three times and so on. I tried to put conditions before the insertion command in the database but it still does not work. I put at your disposal the part of the code which is problematic as well as a screenshot of what happens in the web page after the reloading of it.

Code that insert the message into the BDD :

```
<?php
session_start();
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=myanime', 'root', ''); //connexion a la bdd(base de donnée)...
    $recup_id = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM myanime_follow WHERE id_follow = ?");
    $recup_id->execute(array($_SESSION["id"]));
if(isset($_POST["envoie"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["id"], $_GET["id_following"]) AND !empty($_SESSION["id"]) AND !empty($_GET["id_following"])){
        $id_following = urldecode(intval($_GET["id_following"]));
            if(isset($_POST["message"]) AND !empty($_POST["message"])){
                $lu = 0;
                $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);
                $sending = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO myanime_message(id_expediteur, id_destinataire, messages, lu) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $sending->execute(array($_SESSION["id"], $id_following, $message, $lu));
            }else{
                $erreur = "vous devez envoyer du texte pour l'envoyer";
            }
    }
}
if(isset($erreur)){
    echo $erreur;
}
```

Code that show the message to the user :

```
 <?php
      while($id_following = $recup_id->fetch()){
        $id_pseudo = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM myanime_membre WHERE id = ?");
        $id_pseudo->execute(array($id_following["id_following"]));
        if($id_pseudo->rowCount() == 1){
            $pseudo = $id_pseudo->fetch();
            if(isset($pseudo["pseudo"])){
            ?>
             </br><a href="MyAnime_Messagerie.php?id_following=<?= urlencode($id_following["id_following"])?>">-><?= $pseudo["pseudo"]?></a></br></br>
            <?php
            }
        }
   }
   if(isset($_SESSION["id"], $_GET["id_following"]) AND !empty($_SESSION["id"]) AND !empty($_GET["id_following"])){
    $id_following = urldecode(intval($_GET["id_following"]));
    $compte_principale = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM myanime_membre WHERE id = ?");
        $compte_principale->execute(array($_SESSION["id"]));
        $pseudo_principale = $compte_principale->fetch();
    $message = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM myanime_message WHERE id_expediteur = ? AND id_destinataire = ? OR id_expediteur = ? AND  id_destinataire = ? ORDER BY id");
    $message->execute(array($_SESSION["id"], $id_following, $id_following, $_SESSION["id"]));
    while($recup = $message->fetch()){
        if($recup["id_expediteur"] == $_SESSION["id"]){
            ?>
            <p class="destinataire"><?= $pseudo_principale["pseudo"].": ".$recup["messages"]?></br></p>
            <?php
        }else{
            ?>
            <p class="expediteur"><?= $pseudo["pseudo"].": ".$recup["messages"]?></br></p>
            <?php
        }
    }
}else{
    $erreur = "erreur de connexion";
}
```

[-> Screenshot of what it is doing when reloading the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fDNf.png)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the answer given in this post :/ But it seems to be something similar.

Comment: Just redirect to a new page or same page after your submit and save data into db. search for header redirect with php.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

After your submit you save the data into your database.

Than do a redirect to your form page again or load other page with some message:

```
<?php
 header('Location: loadapage.php');
?>
```

You can send get parameters to the redirect page if needed:

```
<?php
 $value="ok"; // or something
 header("Location: loadapage.php?parm=$value");
?>
```

(From php.net)

[php header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

**Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.**

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=http://stackoverflow.com">
```

Comment: in fact I have to create another page, to tell him to go to this page and come back?